# How does the cloning potion work, exactly?

Tags: candy-box-2

When I drink a cloning potion, what exactly gets cloned? Is the clone identical to me in stats (max hp, and hp remaining at time of cloning?)  do they weild the same weapon, and does that weapon retain magical effects like summoning or fireballs? E.g. If I have an octopus summoning crown, will the clone's crown double the rate? If I drink a health potion, will my clone?

Comment: The cloning potion creates a clone of your character with the same amount of health you have when you use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clone has it's current and max HP set to whatever your current HP is.

It creates a new weapon called "Its fist, its fist". It doesn't retain any upgrades.

Your clone definitely does not drink potions though.

I'm not so great at following JS so I could be wrong. You can have a look for yourself [here](http://candybox2.net/candybox2_uncompressed.js).

```
var PlayerCloneMedium = (function (_super) {
__extends(PlayerCloneMedium, _super);
// Constructor
function PlayerCloneMedium(quest, pos) {
    _super.call(this, quest, pos, new Naming("A clone", "a clone"), new RenderArea(11, 4), new Pos(0, 0), new CollisionBoxCollection(new CollisionBox(this, new Pos(0, 0), new Pos(11, 1)), new CollisionBox(this, new Pos(1, 1), new Pos(9, 1)), new CollisionBox(this, new Pos(2, 2), new Pos(7, 1)), new CollisionBox(this, new Pos(4, 3), new Pos(3, 1))), new QuestEntityMovement());

    // Set the team
    this.setTeam(QuestEntityTeam.PLAYER);

    // Set destructible
    this.setDestructible(true);
    this.setMaxHp(quest.getGame().getPlayer().getHp());
    this.setHp(quest.getGame().getPlayer().getHp());

    // Set the ascii art and the transparent character
    this.getRenderArea().drawArray(Database.getAscii("players/medium"));
    this.setTransparency(new RenderTransparency(" ", "%"));

    // Set the weapon and its delay
    this.addQuestEntityWeapon(new QuestEntityWeapon(this.getQuest(), this, new Naming("Its fists", "its fists"), new CollisionBoxCollection(new CollisionBox(this, new Pos(-1, -1), new Pos(13, 6))), 3));
    this.getLastQuestEntityWeapon().getCloseCombatDelay().setFixedDelay(3);
}
return PlayerCloneMedium;
})(QuestEntity);
```

Comment: That `new QuestEntityWeapon` call there would appear that it isn't actually using the last weapon you used, but instead a new weapon called "Its Fists", with a speed of 3. Haven't dug in the source but it's not doing any kind of call to .getPlayer().getWeapon() or something similar.

Comment: @Cthos I was too lazy to look in the source, but clones definitely don't do nearly as much damage as you do in quests, so I suspect your right.

Comment: I agree. As I said I'm not too great with JS and if you look through this code it's huge. I thought its fist was a placeholder name but looking at it now it does look like it adds its fist to the weapons array and then pulls it off after and adds the delay.